# Работа со строками в условии в Python

Tags: python

Код открывает браузер, кликает на кнопку "accept" во всплывающем баннере. Затем кликает по каждой стране, тем самым открывая списки лиг, а затем окрывает каждую ссылку лиги в новой вкладке (ссылки такого типа: https://www.flashscore.com/football/algeria/coupe-de-la-ligue).

Но мне нужно чтоб открывалась не каждая ссылка, а только та, под которую не попадают исключения и если `if "cup" in league_hrefs: continue` работает отлично и открываются все ссылки, кроме ссылок со строкой "cup", то как мне сделать так, чтоб не открывалась ссылка с лигой из `excluded_leagues`?

```
if excluded_leagues in league_hrefs:
    continue
```

не работает.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.flashscore.com"
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_id("onetrust-accept-btn-handler").click()
time.sleep(2)

for country in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".lmc__block"):
    if country.is_displayed():
        country.click()

for league in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".lmc__templateHref"):
    excluded_leagues = ["cup", "u21", "coupe"]
    league_hrefs = str(league_hrefs.get_attribute("href"))
    if "cup" in league_hrefs:
        continue
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    driver.get(f"{fff}")
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно проверить буквально в одну строку:

```
    if any(exclude in league_hrefs for exclude in excluded_leagues):
        continue
```

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы указываете такое условие, вы проверяете содержание самого объекта списка `excluded_leagues` в `league_hrefs`

```
if excluded_leagues in league_hrefs:
    continue
```

Скорее всего, вам нужно проверить, содержится ли только какой-либо элемент из `excluded_leagues` в `league_hrefs`.

Это можно сделать через вложенный цикл:

```
for elem in excluded_leagues:
    if elem in league_hrefs:
        # действия при наличии совпадений
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно проверить не отсутствие совпадений по списку. Это можно сделать циклом:

```
need_break = False
for c in excluded_leagues:
    if c in league_hrefs:
        need_break = True
        break
if need_break:
    continue
```

Или через пересечения множеств:

```
if len(set(league_hrefs).intersection(set(excluded_leagues))) > 0:
    continue
```